# How to find the number of positive devisors of $50,000$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

How to find the number of positive devisors of $50,000$, I would like to know that what mathematical formulae  I need to use here as it is a big number to calculate mentally, I am sorry to ask if this is too silly question here to ask. Thank you.

Comment: Can you do this with paper, or are you doing it mentally? I'm confused by your use of "by mouth."

Comment: It is very easy to find the prime factorization of $50,000$, and this should help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the prime factorization
$$
n = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_r^{e_r}.
$$
Notice that there is a one-to-one correspondence between positive integer factors of $n$ and $r$-tuples of integers $(d_1, d_2, \dots, d_r)$ such that $0 \le d_i \le e_i$ for each $i$.  Explicitly,
$$
k = p_1^{d_1} p_2^{d_2} \cdots p_r^{d_r} \longmapsto (d_1, d_2, \dots, d_r).
$$
There are $e_i + 1$ possible powers of $p_i$ for each $i$.  Thus, the [total number of divisors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function), $\sigma_0$ is given by
$$
\sigma_0(n) = (e_1 + 1)(e_2 + 1)\cdots(e_r + 1).
$$

---

For your example,
$$
50\,000 = 2^4 \cdot 5^5,
$$
so
$$
\sigma_0(50\,000) = (4 + 1)(5 + 1) = 30.
$$

Answer (score 4):

**hint**. break it into its prime factorisation. then consider the powers of the primes...

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

If the prime factorization of a natural number $\,n\,$ is

$$n=\prod_{i=1}^k p_i^{a_i}\;,\;\;p_i\;\,\text{primes}\;,\;\;a_i\in\Bbb N$$

Then the number of different positive divisors of $\,n\,$ is

$$\prod_{i=1}^k (a_i+1)$$

Answer (score 3):

$$d(50,000)=d(2^45^5)=d(2^4)d(5^5)=(1+4)(1+5)=30$$